# pjsip android stun timeout

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

i make build latest trunk for pjsip on android and get stun error:

```
12-10 00:19:25.340  21917-21917/I/pjsua﹕ pjsua version 2.1-svn for Linux-3.0.15/armv7l initialized
12-10 00:19:25.345  21917-21917/I/pjsua﹕ PJSUA state changed: CREATED --> INIT
12-10 00:19:25.345  21917-21917/I/pjsua﹕ Module "mod-default-handler" registered
12-10 00:19:25.365  21917-21917/I/pjsua﹕ STUN mapped address found/changed: ip1:40865
12-10 00:19:25.365  21917-21917/I/pjsua﹕ STUN resolution success, using ip1:3480, address is ip2:3480
12-10 00:19:27.380  21917-21917/I/pjsua﹕ Error contacting STUN server: Received no response from STUN server (PJLIB_UTIL_ESTUNNOTRESPOND) [status=320010]
12-10 00:19:27.380  21917-21917/I/pjsua﹕ Shutting down, flags=0...
12-10 00:19:27.380  21917-21917/I/pjsua﹕ PJSUA state changed: INIT --> CLOSING
```

Same stun config working fine with same code (on iOS and on old pjsip trunks):

my_config->cfg.stun_srv_cnt = 3;

```
const char *stun = "ip1:3480";
if (stun && strlen(stun)) pj_strdup2_with_null(my_config->pool,&(my_config->cfg.stun_srv[0]),stun);
const char *stun1 = "ip2:3480";
if (stun1 && strlen(stun1)) pj_strdup2_with_null(my_config->pool,&(my_config->cfg.stun_srv[1]),stun1);
const char *stun2 = "ip3:3480";
if (stun2 && strlen(stun2)) pj_strdup2_with_null(my_config->pool,&(my_config->cfg.stun_srv[2]),stun2);
```

ip1-3 is my ip addresses like 1.1.1.1

For me looks strange two things:
1. according logs, stun server was found ip address, but then for unknown reasons start to find again
2. why pjsip lib don't try next server, but just stop library.

i try to do     my_config->cfg.stun_ignore_failure = PJ_TRUE;
but no success...

Answer (score 1):

```
Index: pjsip/sources/pjsip/src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_core.c
===================================================================
--- pjsip.orig/sources/pjsip/src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_core.c 2013-03-31 19:06:27.202008510 +0200
+++ pjsip/sources/pjsip/src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_core.c  2013-03-31 19:06:31.322008598 +0200
@@ -1954,7 +1954,7 @@
             pj_ntohs(pjsua_var.stun_srv.ipv4.sin_port);
    status = pjstun_get_mapped_addr2(&pjsua_var.cp.factory, &stun_opt,
                     1, &sock, &p_pub_addr->ipv4);
-   if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
+   if (status != PJ_SUCCESS && !pjsua_var.ua_cfg.stun_ignore_failure) {
        pjsua_perror(THIS_FILE, "Error contacting STUN server", status);
        pj_sock_close(sock);
        return status;
```

Thank you for Regis from csipsimple...